# Sumatorio variables en java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo una variable double declarada dentro de un bucle for, esta variable me devuelve diferentes valores según el bucle recorre el array list.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ticketAdapter.mTicket.mLines.size(); i++){
                double totalNoVATt = ticketAdapter.mTicket.mLines.get(i).mTotalNoVAT * ticketAdapter.mTicket.mLines.get(i).mUnits;
                Log.i("MainActivity","totalnovat "+ totalNoVATt);
            }
```

Quería saber como guardar en una variable el sumatorio de estos valores que me devuelve.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declara una variable del mismo tipo (Double) fuera del bucle y le sumas la cantidad calculada en cada iteración dentro del bucle, algo así:

```
double sumatoria = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < ticketAdapter.mTicket.mLines.size(); i++){
    double totalNoVATt = ticketAdapter.mTicket.mLines.get(i).mTotalNoVAT * ticketAdapter.mTicket.mLines.get(i).mUnits;
    sumatoria += totalNoVATt;
    Log.i("MainActivity","totalnovat "+ totalNoVATt);
}
System.out.println(sumatoria);
```

Comment: Gracias por ayudar pero es mejor esperar a que el OP ponga su problema una vez intentado. Un saludo

Comment: El OP ya ha investigado e intentado solucionar su problema. Si es nuevo en el lenguaje Java es normal que tenga dudas. La pregunta está bien formulada y la respuesta es correcta. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias a todos por echarme una mano, al final he podido sacarlo haciendo algo similar:for(int f = 0; f < vatottal.size();f++) {
                    sumatotalvat = sumatotalvat + vatottal.get(f);
                } Un saludo

Comment: @J.Burrueco si te ha servido, marca como aceptada la respuesta de Macaroni

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes usar Java 8 (o superior), quizás prefieras:

```
double sumatorio = ticketAdapter.mTicket.mLines.stream().mapToDouble( m -> m.mTotalNoVAT * m.mUnits ).sum();
```